# layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer when trying to connect dense layer to LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm playing with a multiclass classification problem and for fun I wanted to try different models. I found a [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-lstm-using-tensorflow-2-0-d88627c10a35) that used LSTM for classification and was trying to adjust my model to work.

Here is my model:

```
  from tensorflow import keras
  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Bidirectional, LSTM
  from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam 

  x_train_shape = X_train.shape[1]
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(x_train_shape, activation='tanh', input_dim=x_train_shape))
  # model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
  
  # model.add(Dense(x_train_shape, activation='tanh'))
  # model.add(Dense(x_train_shape, activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dense(len(labels), activation='softmax'))


  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy', 'TopKCategoricalAccuracy', 'FalsePositives'])

  model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=200)
```

It returns this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 109]
```

If I uncomment the dense layers under LSTM and comment the LSTM, the model works so it's def related to the LSTM line.

How can I connect an LSTM layer to a dense for multiclass classification?

Comment: the input of an LSTM layer is `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. You have a dense layer before LSTM, the output of dense layer is `[batch, feature]`. That's why you get this error. What is your X_train?

Comment: @Reza Thank you - what do you mean x_train? it's a df of features and y is the labels

Comment: I mean what is the content of your features? the blog you included is talking of text classification. You can see in the blog, there is an embedding layer before LSTM and the output of embedding layer is `[batch, vocab_size, embedding_dim]` which matches with what LSTM is expecting

Comment: @Reza for this it's a list of columns from a dataframe that I want to use to predict the category of the data I'm predicting.

Comment: as I understand your problem don't need a recurrent network... simple dense layers do the jobs

Comment: @MarcoCerliani It's okay. I just want to learn and see different approaches to the same problem to understand a neural network approach to classification better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a `TimeDistributed` layer around the `Dense` layer. Here's an example with bogus data:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 1, 10)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)

assert X_train.ndim == 3

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(8)))

model.add(Dense(8, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[-1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam")

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=8)
```

```
Train on 100 samples
  8/100 [=>............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.2984
 80/100 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.2863
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 950us/sample - loss: 2.2984
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I tried it, I got the same type of error "    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_56 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 109]"

Comment: You need to have the same number of dimensions than my example. Try unsqueezing with `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 1)`

Comment: It's very important that you have 3 dimensions. `assert X_train.ndim == 3`

Comment: is there a way I can apply it to my dataset? You helped me convert the y to categorical earlier today. Can I use that dataset?

Comment: It will work with any dataset with shape `(n_samples, time_steps, features)`

Comment: oh i think I get it..you are saying I have to add time step to my X_train ?

Comment: Yes exactly. You _need_ 3D input.

Comment: thank you, I get it now. it's not a total fit for my classification problem but I'll play with it further and at least I know where my problem was. Thank you Nicolas.